# View Error @Foreach (var item...) Model/Controller/View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller

Heey,

I have a problem which seems stupid but i just can't fix it, and i dont know why i think im overlooking it so i need a new set of eyes.

I Got a model Class:

```
namespace LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudenNr { get; set; }
        public string Naam { get; set; }
        public string Woonplaats { get; set; }
        public string Adres { get; set; }
        public int TelefoonNr { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a Controller:

```
namespace LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ArticleController : Controller
    {
        private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        private int _nextId = 1;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StudentNr, Naam, Woonplaats, Adres, TelefoonNr, School FROM [Table] ORDER BY StudentNr DESC", con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                students.Add(new Student() { StudenNr = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), Naam = dr[1].ToString(), Woonplaats = dr[2].ToString(), Adres = dr[3].ToString(), TelefoonNr = int.Parse(dr[4].ToString()), School = dr[5].ToString() });
            }
            return View(students);

        }
    }
}
```

And a View:

```
@model  IEnumerable<LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>This is the Index</h2>
<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>StudentNummer</td>
            <td>Naam</td>
            <td>Woonplaats</td>
            <td>Adres</td>
            <td>Telefoonnummer</td>
            <td>School</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

@foreach (var item in LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Models.Student)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.StudenNr</td>
        <td>@item.Naam</td>
        <td>@item.Woonplaats</td>
        <td>@item.Adres</td>
        <td>@item.TelefoonNr</td>
        <td>@item.School</td>


    </tr>

}
</table>
```

Now my problem is that when i run it everything looks alright, ( i know its messy code but just want it to work )
but i get this problem/error.

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0119: 'LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Models.Student'
>   is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

```
Line 20: 
Line 21: 
Line 22: @foreach (var item in LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Models.Student)
Line 23: {
Line 24:     <tr>
```

what is going wrong it has to be a small problem i think and hopefully easy to fix i hope you guys cant help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to loop through `Student`, but your Model is `IEnumerable<Student>`. Try to loop through `Model`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.StudenNr</td>
        <td>@item.Naam</td>
        <td>@item.Woonplaats</td>
        <td>@item.Adres</td>
        <td>@item.TelefoonNr</td>
        <td>@item.School</td>       
    </tr>    
}
```

Comment: getting this error: 
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_jkxy3fxw.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: at the same line, at the word Model. so i changed the code to this:
@foreach (LaatsteStudentWebAPI.Models.Student item in Model)
but still the same error

Comment: Probably you need to clean and recompile. I have tested the code and it is working fine.